# How to call many databases without hard-coding?

Tags: apache, apache-camel, blueprint-osgi, apache-servicemix

I have following scenario:

There are many sites/departments and every site has it's own ServiceMix and different number of databases. Those databases are grouped, for example there are two groups: production_one and production_two.

On every site I deployed bundles as a datasource, one datasource for every database.

Datasource: blueprint.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<blueprint xmlns="http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:cxf="http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint/cxf"
       xmlns:cm="http://aries.apache.org/blueprint/xmlns/blueprint-cm/v1.0.0"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
         http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0 http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0/blueprint.xsd
         http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint/camel-blueprint.xsd">


<!-- Properties -->
<!-- blueprint property placeholders, that will use etc/datasources.cfg as the properties file -->
<cm:property-placeholder id="db.placeholder" persistent-id="datasources">
</cm:property-placeholder>


<!-- Datasource -->
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
      destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver" />
    <property name="url"
              value="jdbc:sqlserver://${bundle_ds_1_db_host}:${bundle_ds_1_db_port};databaseName=${bundle_ds_1_db_database};" />
    <property name="username" value="${bundle_ds_1_db_username}" />
    <property name="password" value="${bundle_ds_1_db_password}" />
</bean>

<!-- Init database-->
<bean id="initDatabase"
      class="com.xyz.mssql.ds.DatabaseInitBean"
      init-method="create" destroy-method="destroy">
    <property name="ds" ref="dataSource" />
</bean>

<service ref="dataSource" interface="javax.sql.DataSource">
    <service-properties>
        <entry key="datasource.name" value="${bundle_ds_1_ds_name}" />
        <entry key="datasource.type" value="${bundle_ds_1_ds_type}" />
        <entry key="datasource.id" value="${bundle_ds_1_ds_id}" />
        <entry key="datasource.group_id" value="${bundle_ds_1_ds_group_id}" />
    </service-properties>
</service>
```

There is also bundle, which receives a SOAP message via cxf and process it by calling database:

CXF: blueprint.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <blueprint xmlns="http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:cxf="http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint/cxf"
    xmlns:cm="http://aries.apache.org/blueprint/xmlns/blueprint-cm/v1.0.0"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
             http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0 http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0/blueprint.xsd
             http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint/cxf http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint/cxf/camel-cxf.xsd
             http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint     http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint/camel-blueprint.xsd">

    <cxf:cxfEndpoint id="processXEndpoint" address="/mssql-soap1/"
        serviceClass="com.xyz.mssql.soap1.ProcessXService" />

    <bean id="saveDataProcessor"
        class="com.xyz.mssql.soap1.SaveDataProcessor">
        <property name="ds" ref="dataSource" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="getDataProcessor"
        class="com.xyz.mssql.soap1.GetDataProcessor">
        <property name="ds" ref="dataSource" />
    </bean>


    <!-- DataSource -->
    <reference id="dataSource" interface="javax.sql.DataSource"
        filter="(datasource.name=mssql-ds-1)">
        <reference-listener bind-method="onBind"
            unbind-method="onUnbind">
            <bean class="com.xyz.mssql.soap1.ListenerBean" />
        </reference-listener>
    </reference>

    <!-- Camel Context -->
    <camelContext xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint">
        <route id="cxf">
            <from uri="cxf:bean:processXEndpoint" />
            <recipientList>
                <simple>direct:${header.operationName}</simple>
            </recipientList>
        </route>
        <route id="saveRoute">
            <from uri="direct:saveData" />
            <log message="Calling saveData" />
            <process ref="saveDataProcessor" />
        </route>
        <route id="getRoute">
            <from uri="direct:getData" />
            <log message="Call getData" />
            <process ref="getDataProcessor" />
        </route>
    </camelContext>
</blueprint>
```

The problem is, that following code inject to bean (ex: SaveDataProcessor) only one datasource resolved by it's name "datasource.name=mssql-ds-1", but I need to call many databases and on every servicemix installation there will be different number of them.

I need to call all databases (datasources) which have same type, for example "datasource.type=production_one". 
Is it possible? How to do it?

How to pass to bean an array of datasources, or call this bean against every datasource which meet same conditions (name, type and so on).

Comment: If you change your filter criteria when requesting the data source service to be the type, and you register multiple data sources with that type, then the service lookup should return you a list of all data sources, not just one.